# Why is 'is' used in this sentence rather than 'was'?

Tags: tense, verbs, tense-agreement

Here are the sentences :

Since life began in the oceans, most life, including freshwater life, has a chemical composition more like the ocean than fresh water. It appears that most freshwater life did not originate in fresh water, but **is** secondarily adapted, having passed from ocean to land and then back again to fresh water.

Is it OK to see this '**is**' as a problem of tense disagreement? or not?
If not, why?

Comment: It;s fine the way it is. Obviously the subject (most freshwater life) still exists, and still has those secondary adaptations. Bear in mind that we can say *The appearance of life on Earth **is*** (or ***was***) *of cosmic significance*. With such an all-embracing subject, it's often stylistically better to use Present Tense wherever possible, to add "immediacy" (and avoid sounding like a history teacher! :)

Comment: Note that the writer had no choice with *life **began***, but they steered away from *has **had** a chemical composition* - which doubtless some pedants would say is what it *should* have said, according to strict temporal "logic".

Comment: Thank you for your illuminating explanations :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "*the writer had no choice with **life began**, but they steered away from **has had a chemical composition*** <-- I cannot tell for sure, but I think the writer is using the other type of *since*. In other words it doesn't mean *from the time that*, it means *because* -  and that's why no past perfect is required there.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: That never occurred to me, but now I think that probably *was* *(**is**?!)* the intended sense. But it's odd how smoothly the words can take either sense here - a verbal version of the ["Necker Cube"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necker_cube) visual illusion.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no problem of tense agreements.

Abstracting out the key portion of the sentence you ask about, we obtain

> Most freshwater life is secondarily adapted.

Although the word *adapted* is obviously derived as the past participle of the verb *adapt*, here it is being used as a modifier, and in the sense that [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adapted) defines as

> “suited by nature, character, or design to a particular use, purpose, or situation → used with *to* or *for*”

And the (pared-down) sentence constitutes an assertion about the current state of the modern-day life forms under discussion. That’s why the author uses the present tense *is*. It’s completely analogous to this passage:

> Whales and other cetaceans are descended from land mammals—in fact, they are the closest living relatives of the hippopotamuses. But over their history, their limbs evolved, with their forelimbs becoming flippers and their external hind legs disappearing altogether. Likewise, their nasal passage shifted so that it opens at the top of their head as the blowhole. Because of these and other similar changes, our modern whales **are** now marvelously **adapted** to their oceanic environment.